# add dummy column in LINQ fetch query

Tags: asp.net, linq

How to return the List in LINQ query while adding a dummy column,
How to return qry as LIST.

```
public static List<MSDNMagazine.emp> FetchEmp() 
{
    try
    {
        MSDNMagazine.JsonDataContext context = new MSDNMagazine.JsonDataContext(); 
        var qry = from p in context.emps 
        select new
        {
            emp_cod = p.emp_cod,
            emp_nam = p.emp_nam,
            test = "0"
        };
        return (List< >)qry; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw ex; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select new emp //the name of the class
{
    emp_cod = p.emp_cod,
    emp_nam = p.emp_nam,
    test = "0"
};
return qry.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ToList() Extension method.

```
return qry.ToList();
```

Comment: the way it's spelled now its an anonymous type, he'll get a type mismatch.